# Nested Queries with group by and max to C# linq

Tags: c#, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

I have the following TSQL

```
SELECT COUNT(M.MuseumID) as [ACTIVECARDHOLDERS] 
FROM Museum AS M
WHERE M.MuseumID IN
     (SELECT MAX(X.MuseumID) AS MuseumID 
      FROM (SELECT BioStation.[MuseumID]
                  ,BioStation.[PersonID] 
                  ,ISNULL(M.ISCARDINVALIDATED,0) AS [ISCARDINVALIDATED] 
             FROM Museum AS M
                  INNER JOIN BioStation ON BioStation.MuseumID = Museum.MuseumID
             WHERE M.CASESTATE=7 AND M.CASESTATUS=6) AS X 
      GROUP BY X.PERSONID) 
AND ISNULL(M.ISCARDINVALIDATED,0)=0;
```

I'm trying to convert to linq in C#, starting with the inner most query, however I'm unsure how to nest them in linq with group\max. This is what I have so far that's bug free:

```
var query = (from m in dbContext.Museum
             join b in dbContext.BioStation on m.MuseumID equals b.MuseumID
             where m.CaseState == 7 && m.CaseStatus == 6
             select new {b.MuseumID, b.PersonID, IsCardInvalidated = (m.IsCardInvalidated == null ? false : m.IsCardInvalidated) }).AsQueryable();
```

Any help with the translation would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It will be easier if you describe what you are trying to achieve and also explain it with an example of data and the desired output

Comment: I'm trying to take a sql query, which basically brings me back a count of all Museum ID cards that are active, and translate that to a linq statement. The join is needed to ensure the data is specific to those museum visitors whom have been checked into the biostation first to get their info. and then processed further to a Museum Identification. The rest are just checks for duplicates and that a card is not invalid.